# jQuery on change doesnt fire when the same input is re-entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, onchange

I have this form where you enter something in the input field and i have added an onchange event listener to throw an alert when the value is changed. Apparently the code works in Chrome but in **Firefox** it doesnt work if we re-enter the same text.

Example:

1st try --> Enters the text -> Hello. (Alerts as Text changed).
2nd try --> Enters the text -> Hello. (again) (on Change event isnt called).

Can anyone tell me why this is happening ? Thank you for your time in advance :).

Here is a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/neoragex/6yMsf/1/

Comment: I have tried your fiddle in firefox and it seems to work... strange.. is it just supposed to show a popup where it says: "text changed"?

Comment: Observed same behavior in chrome and firefox

Comment: @ClydeFrog Yes it does give a popup when the value is changed. But try entering the same value again. The event listener wont fire for some reason.

Comment: I mean.
Enter something : Hello
Alerts (Text changed).
Enter something : Hello        . AGAIN .
Nothing happens :(.

Comment: What do you want to achieve. Its not firing because it shouldnt . Its `onchange` event means `on change of text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may handle blur event. It would be fired even if value is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because the event only fires when the value of the input field changes - You're setting the same value again, so no change happens as far as the browser is concerned.

Comment: Is there a way to make the onchange event fire on every input ?  Thank you for replying :)

Comment: As suggested by varela, use the blur event instead - It will fire regardless of value. You can add a check to make sure the value isn't null or empty just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').on('blur',function() {    
       alert($(this).val());
    });    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with keyup event. This event fire when a key press.